# Powershell script showing UNKN state in Check_MK

Tags: powershell, nagios, check-mk

I have a simple powershell script that checks the logged in users on a Windows Server (qwinsta).
It works perfectly with Nagios/NRPE, I can also execute the script locally on the Windows Server, but I can't get it to work with Check_MK.
I copied the script to the **%ProgramData%\agent\local** folder, a rescan on the Check_MK server finds the script, but the service status is UNKN (check failed - please submit a crash report!).

The script looks like this:

```
(qwinsta.exe) | findstr /v Disc | findstr /v Conn | findstr /v Listen | foreach { (($_.trim() -replace "\s+",","))} | ConvertFrom-Csv | findstr.exe USERNAME > C:\temp\users.txt
```

And then the customization for the Nagios output:

```
(Get-Content C:\temp\users.txt) -replace 'USERNAME', '' -replace ':','' | Set-Content C:\temp\users.txt 
$lines = Get-Content C:\Temp\users.txt 
$var=($lines|group|?{$_.count -ge 1}|Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
```

I suspect the problem is in the way I wrote the Nagios output in Powershell:

```
if ($LoggedOnUsers -lt 1){<br>
    $NagiosStatus = "0"<br>
    Write-Host "No users are logged on"<br>
    }<br>
else <br>
    {<br>
     if (($Today -like "Saturday" -OR $Today -like "Sunday") -AND ($LoggedOnUsers -eq 1)) <br>
     {<br>
                $NagiosStatus = "2"<br>
                if ($LoggedOnUsers -eq 1) {<br>
                    Write-Host "$LoggedOnUsers user logged on: $var"<br>
                }<br>
                else {<br>
                    Write-Host "$LoggedOnUsers users logged on: $var"<br>
                }<br>
            }<br>
    else <br>
    {<br>
                if (($now -lt $max) -AND ($now -gt $min)) {<br>
                $NagiosStatus = "1"<br>
                if ($LoggedOnUsers -eq 1) {<br>
                    Write-Host "$LoggedOnUsers user logged on: $var "<br>
                }<br>
                else {<br>
                    Write-Host "$LoggedOnUsers users logged on: $var"<br>
                }<br>
            }<br>
            else {<br>
                $NagiosStatus = "2" <br>
                if ($LoggedOnUsers -eq 1) {<br>
                    Write-Host "$LoggedOnUsers user logged on: $var"<br>
                    }<br>
                else {<br>
                    Write-Host "$LoggedOnUsers users logged on: $var"<br>
                }<br>
            }<br>
    }<br>
    }<br>
exit $NagiosStatus<br>
```

Not sure how to write the output for Check_mk.
Any ideas welcome.

This is how the output looks in Nagios:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrL71.png)

Comment: Can you show example of expected output (base on example output of `qwinsta`) ?  It seems that starting using something like: `(qwinsta) -replace ' +',',' | ConvertFrom-csv | ft` might be easier to get to a desired result (and better readable for anyone changing this script somewhere in the future....)

Answer (score 1):

```
(qwinsta) -replace ' SESSIONNAME','_SESSIONNAME' -replace ' +',',' |
   ConvertFrom-csv | 
   Where-Object { $_.STATE -Match 'Active' } | 
   Select-Object USERNAME | 
   Get-Unique |
   Join-String -Property {$_.USERNAME} -Separator ','
```

- First replace ' SESSIONNAME' by '_SESSIONNAME', this is done to make the columns split nicely.
- Replace all 1 or more spaced (`' +'`) by a `','`.
- Select the 'Active' ones (you can change this when you need other states too
- Select the USERNAME
- Each USERNAME just ones, so `Get-Unique`
- Join the result with a ',' as separator

OK, I am not sure about this last parts, was not able to test because I only have one USERNAME , and my Powershell scripting levels are LOW

Comment: Hi Luuk, thanks, it still doesn't work. I have added a screenshot of Nagios in the original post. I have the following entry in nsclient.ini:
check_users = cmd /c echo scripts\check_users.ps1; exit($lastexitcode) | PowerShell.exe -command - . I think the Check_MK agent needs something similar, I don't know exactly in which file

Comment: Hi Luuk, I have found the error. I added the service check definition in check_mk.yml using "tab" instead of "space". Therefore Check_mk ignored this particular line. Now it works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: code should not be posted in a comment, and certainly not code  which is not mentioned in the question.... 